# How to execute CMake's default find module from my own find module with the same name?

Tags: cmake

For some reason I want to extend a find module (`FindThreads` in my case) to do some specific stuff if CMake's `FindThreads` fails. For the ordinary developer of other parts of our software system this should happen transparently, such that s/he could call `find_package(Threads)` as usual, so I don't want to give my own find module an exclusive name.

My idea is to add my own `FindThreads.cmake` in a folder contained in the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. Because `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` has priority `find_package(Threads)` will execute my own `FindThreads.cmake`.

But, inside my own `FindThreads.cmake` I need to execute `find_package(Threads ...)` such that it executes CMake's original `FindThreads.cmake`. **How to do that?**

If that fails my own `FindThreads.cmake` should try to add a specific Threads lib.

Unfortunately, there is no option `NO_CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` for `find_package` to fall back to CMake's own find modules and it seems not to be possible to pass a search path (for example `${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules`) to `find_package` to override `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

### Versions

- CMake 3.5 on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)
- CMake 3.14 on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` before `find_package` call and restore the variable after the call:

```
# Save old value of CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH_OLD ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
# Temporary replace CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules")
# Call find_package() with specific CMAKE_MODULE_PATH set.
find_package(Threads ...)
# Restore CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH_OLD})
```

Note, that `FindXXX.cmake` is executed in the same *scope* as the caller code, so restoring `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable is needed even if your script no longer calls `find_package` but simply returns.

Also, it is better to use some *unique* variable's *name* instead of `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH_OLD`: it is possible that caller already uses that variable for its own purposes. E.g. you may add some suffix to the variable's name which related to your organization or is unlikely to be used by others.

Comment: Thanks, that should work although I hoped for a solution without such a temporary context change. I feel a little uncomfortable with that, because future developers might not notice it.

To avoid the scope problem with `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH_OLD` I will try to put the whole code in a function to be on the safe side.