# Expand FindModule.cmake logic with a wrapper file

Tags: c++, cmake

There are a lot of libraries' packages which do not provide a CMake config file, and in order to find and use them with cmake, one would have to resort to using a `FindPackage.cmake` script. Some scripts (i.e. SDL) are available within the cmake itself, so finding a package is relatively easy.
Though in my case, SDL-searching scripts (SDL, SDL_image, SDL_mixer) are available almost since the dawn of modern cmake (at least 3.1), they do not provide the means for the modern approach - they do not define imported cmake Targets. SDL as a target is available only since 3.19, and it does not define `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property.
So, the logical thing is to define those targets and properties.
A naive approach would possibly be to just copy the contents of `FindSDL.cmake` from a newer cmake bundle and paste it with modifications.
But I would like to keep those files from a cmake bundle (or another good enough script from external source) intact and just wrap them.
So, the main `CMakeLists.txt` would be like:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules")
find_package(SDL REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL_mixer REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL_image REQUIRED)
```

`cmake/modules/FindSDL.cmake`:

```
find_package(SDL REQUIRED)

if (NOT TARGET SDL::SDL)
# add target and properties here
endif()
```

However, the way I wrote it will not work because of the endless recursion.

*How could I resolve the endless recursion with `find_package` when writing a wrapper `FindPackage.cmake` that uses the original `FindPackage.cmake` file?*

---

This looks promising:
[How to execute CMake's default find module from my own find module with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184814/how-to-execute-cmakes-default-find-module-from-my-own-find-module-with-the-same)

Comment: So, does the solution in the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184814/how-to-execute-cmakes-default-find-module-from-my-own-find-module-with-the-same) works for you? As far as I understand, it should resolve your first problem (avoid recursion). As for redirecting arguments to the inner `FindSDL.cmake`, you could try to include it via `include` instead of `find_package`: `include(FindSDL)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it does work for the first question. For the second one: user's main CMakeLists code should be agnostic of whether FindSDL is extended or not. `find_package` is the intended way of searching for packages

Comment: About your second question - have you looked at the [FindPackageHandleStandardArgs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html) module?

Comment: @u-235 yes, I have. Calling it after `find_package(SDL)` with the same arguments as `FindSDL.cmake` calls seems to work for `find_package(SDL REQUIRED)`. But I didn't try to figure out its internals to redirect the arguments like `find_package(SDL ${ARGS})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to delete the current path from `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` before calling `find_package()`, and then restore it.

```
list(REMOVE_ITEM CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
find_package(SDL)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

if (NOT TARGET SDL::SDL)
# add target and properties here
endif()
```

Comment: This is already referenced in the link by Tsyvarev's answer

Comment: There is a significant difference - in my case `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is not completely overridden. This may be important if this variable contains other paths as well.

Comment: yes, this does make sence